# package for parallel columns randomly omits pages (paracol)

Tags: formatting, columns, parallel, parcolumns

I've been using `paracol` for a few days now. I think it is a nice package for parallel columns. There is one problem, however, which strikes me. Sometimes (only sometimes) the pdf that results from my compilation misses a page. When I change something in the document it *may* happen that the page reappears and a few changes later the page (or possibly another) is missing again.

Why is that so? Any solutions? This is rather inconvenient.

---

Brief update 06 May 2013:  contacted the package author.

---

Brief update 02 June 2013:  an updated version of `paracol` is now available on CTAN.

---

Here is a MWE, which -- on my machine (fully up to date) -- illustrates the problem (i.e., the first page is left out):

```
 % !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, DIV=16]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{paracol}{2}
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\end{paracol}

\section{Section}
\begin{paracol}{2}
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\end{paracol}

\section{Section}
\begin{paracol}{2}
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\end{paracol}

\section{Section}
\begin{paracol}{2}
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since this may be a package bug, closing as TL seems appropriate. If the package author provides a fix or otherwise, edit the question with an update and it should appear in the "re-open" section on the [review page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/review).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the package maintainer, who confirmed that it is a bug. He quickly responded and provided a fix a few hours later which he intends to include in the next update of `paracol` to version 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot help for the observed issue, that I must confirm.

But if you would invoke the sectioning commands as intended by the package, everything would work fine (code shortened to be almost minimal):

<sup>Note, that I removed the package option for paper and font size, since `a4` and `11pt` are the defaults anyway (and the documented option setting for paper size would have been `paper=a4`). Also you should not ignore the warning about bad type area settings, with `DIV=12` this warning would disappear.</sup>

```
\documentclass[DIV=16]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}[\section{Section 1}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.

\switchcolumn*[\section{Section 2}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.

\switchcolumn*[\section{Section 3}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!

\switchcolumn*[\section{Section 4}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addition in reaction to comment:*

The following longer example compiled absolutely fine for me. I took OP’s example, altered it according `paracol`’s documentation, and added the example “Ode To Joy” from doc with slight changes:

<sup>There are some font warnings I did not have some days ago, but I get them now after a `luatex` and `luaotfload` update.</sup>

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, DIV=16]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}[\section{First Section}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.

\switchcolumn*[\section{Second Section}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.

\switchcolumn*[\section{Third Section}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.

\switchcolumn*[\section{Fourth Section}]
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\switchcolumn*
Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu sein; Wer ein holdes Weib errungen, mische seinen Jubel ein! Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund! Und wer’s nie gekonnt, der stehle weinend sich aus diesem Bund!
\switchcolumn
Let the man who has had the fortune To be a helper to his friend, And the man who has won a noble woman, Join in our chorus of jubilation! Yes, even if he holds but one soul As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow. As his own in all the world! But let the man who knows nothing of this Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\end{paracol}

\bigskip

\newenvironment{Gverse}{\begin{leftcolumn*}
  \begin{myverse}}
  {\end{myverse}\end{leftcolumn*}}
\newenvironment{Everse}{\begin{rightcolumn}\begin{myverse}}
  {\end{myverse}\end{rightcolumn}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myverse}{\leftmargini0pt\partopsep0pt\verse}{\endverse}

\begin{paracol}{2}[ % changed environment here
\centerline{\Large An Die Freude/To Joy}\smallskip
\centerline{\large Friedrich Schiller}\smallskip
The following is the libretto of the fourth movement of Beethoven's Ninth
Symphony, his adaptation of Schiller's ode ``An Die Freude'' (or ``To Joy'' in
English). Beethoven's additions and revisions are indicated in italics.] % line removed afterwards
\begin{Gverse}
\itshape O Freunde, nicht diese T\"one! \\
Sondern la{\ss}t uns angenehmere anstimmen und freu\-denvollere
\footnote{Dieser Teil wurde von Beethoven hinzugef\"ugt.}. % changed to German
\end{Gverse}
\begin{Everse}
\itshape Oh friends, no more of these sad tones!\\
Let us rather raise our voices together\\
In more pleasant and joyful tones
\footnote{This part was added by Beethoven.} % removed label
\end{Everse}
\begin{Gverse}
Freude!\\
Freude, sch\"oner G\"otterfunken
Tochter aus Elysium,\\
Wir betreten feuertrunken,
Himmlische, dein Heiligtum!\\
Deine Zauber binden wieder,
{\itshape Was die Mode streng geteilt;\\
Alle Menschen werden Br\"uder\footnote{
Original: Was der Mode Schwert geteilt;\\
Bettler werden F\"urstenbr\"uder,},}
Wo dein sanfter Fl\"u\-gel weilt
\end{Gverse}
\begin{Everse}
Joy! \\
Joy, thou shining spark of God,\\
Daughter of Elysium,\\
With fiery rapture, goddess,\\
We approach thy shrine.\\
Your magic reunites\\
{\itshape That which stern custom has parted;\\
All humans will become brothere\footnote{
Original: 
What custom's sword has parted;\\
Beggars become princes' brothers}}\\
Under your protective wing.
\end{Everse}
\begin{Gverse}
Wem der gro{\ss}e Wurf gelungen,
eines Freundes Freund zu sein;\\
Wer ein holdes Weib errungen,
mische seinen Jubel ein!\\
Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele 
sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund!\\
Und wer's nie gekonnt, der stehle 
weinend sich aus diesem Bund! 
\end{Gverse}
\begin{Everse}
Let the man who has had the fortune\\
To be a helper to his friend,\\
And the man who has won a noble woman,\\
Join in our chorus of jubilation!\\
Yes, even if he holds but one soul\\
As his own in all the world!\\
But let the man who knows nothing of this\\
Steal away alone and in sorrow.
\end{Everse}
\begin{Gverse}
Freude trinken alle Wesen
an den Br\"usten der Natur;\\
Alle Guten, all B\"osen
folgen ihrer Rosenspur.\\
K\"usse gab sie uns und Reben,
einen Freund, gepr\"uft im Tod;\\
Wollust ward dem Wurm gegeben,
und der Cherub steht vor Gott. 
\end{Gverse}
\begin{Everse}
All the world's creatures drink\\
From the breasts of nature;\\
Both the good and the evil\\
Follow her trail of roses.\\
She gave us kisses and wine\\
And a friend loyal unto death;\\
She gave the joy of life to the lowliest,\\
And to the angels who dwell with God. 
\end{Everse}
\begin{Gverse}
Froh, wie seine Sonnen fliegen 
durch des Himmels pr\"acht'gen Plan,\\
Laufet, Br\"uder, eure Bahn,
freudig, wie ein Held zum Siegen. 
\end{Gverse}
\begin{Everse}
Joyous, as his suns speed\\
Through the glorious order of Heaven,\\
Hasten, brothers, on your way,\\
Joyful as a hero to victory.
\end{Everse}
\begin{Gverse}
Seid umschlungen, Millionen! 
Diesen Ku{\ss} der ganzen Welt!\\
Br\"uder, \"uber'm Sternenzelt
mu{\ss} ein lieber Vater woh\-nen. 
\end{Gverse}
\begin{Everse}
Be embraced, all ye millions!\\
With a kiss for all the world!\\
Brothers, beyond the stars\\
Surely dwells a loving Father. 
\end{Everse}
\begin{Gverse}
Ihr st\"urzt nieder, Millionen?
Ahnest du den Sch\"opfer, Welt?\\
Such'ihn \"uberm Sternenzelt! 
\"Uber Sternen mu{\ss} er wohnen.
\end{Gverse}
\begin{Everse}
Do you kneel before him, oh millions?\\
Do you sense the Creator's presence?\\
Seek him beyond the stars!\\
He must dwell beyond the stars.
\end{Everse}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your approach does not seem to work. You shortened the paragraphs. It is only due to the shortened paragraphs that your source compiles without a missing first page. When do not shorten the paragraphs, and only remove `\section{Section}` and add `\begin{paracol}{2}[\section{Section 1}]` to my document, the page is still missing.

Comment: No, I shortened only for the answer. I did my test with a copy of your mwe! Note, that I removed beginning and ending of `paracol` in between, too.